# Running a PythonScript as a process and reading Standard Output issue

Tags: c#, python, .net

I am trying to run a python script as a process to which I pass a couple of parameters and then read standard output. I have a little console app and a dummy script that works fine, but when I do the same thing in my WebApi project, Standard Output is always blank, and I cannot figure out why. My code follows:

**Console App**

```
class Program
    {
       private static string Foo(string inputString)
       {
           string result = String.Empty;
           ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
           start.FileName = "python";
           start.Arguments = string.Format(" {0} {1} {2}", @"*path*\runner.py", @"*path*\test2.py", inputString);
           start.UseShellExecute = false;
           start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
           using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
           {
               using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
               {
                   result = reader.ReadToEnd();
               }
           }
           return result;
       }

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var result = Foo("flibble");
           Console.Write(result);
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
    }
```

**runner.py (for the console app)**

```
import sys, imp

test = imp.load_source('test',sys.argv[1])
result = test.hello(sys.argv[2])
```

**test2.py (from the console app)**

```
import sys

def hello(inputString):
   sys.stdout.write(inputString)
   return
```

That is the end of what I have that works, now onto the code where the issue is:

**ApiEndpoint**

```
  [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult TestEndpoint()
        {
            string postedJson = ReadRawBuffer().Result;
            if (postedJson == null) throw new ArgumentException("Request is null");
            var result = _pythonOperations.Foo(postedJson);
            // Deal with result
            return Ok();
        }
```

**_pythonOperations.Foo()**

```
  public string Foo(string inputString)
        {
            string result;
            var start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = _pathToPythonExecutable,
                Arguments = string.Format(" {0} {1} {2}", _pathToPythonRunnerScript, _pathToPythonFooScript, inputString),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**pythonRunnerScript**

```
import sys, imp

module = imp.load_source('foo', sys.argv[1])
module.Foo(sys.argv[2])
```

**Foo script**

```
import sys

def Foo(inputString)
    outputString = "output"
    sys.stdout.write(outputString)
    return
```

This is quite possibly one of the longest posts I have made, so thanks for taking the time to read it, and hopefully I can get a solution to this.

Cheers

Comment: Turns out the format I was passing in was wrong. I was using Postman REST Api client, and pasting the huge amounts of data into their request content window truncated it, leaving me with half a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the format I was passing in was wrong. I was using Postman REST Api client, and pasting the huge amounts of data into their request content window truncated it, leaving me with half a line. Once this was sorted, everything ran through ok.